# How to edit x-axis length but also maintain plot dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Below I have my code to plot my graph.

```
#can change the 'iloc[x:y]' component to plot sections of chart

#ax = df['Data'].iloc[300:].plot(color = 'black', title = 'Past vs. Expected Future Path')
ax = df.plot('Date','Data',color = 'black', title = 'Past vs. Expected Future Path')

df.loc[df.index >= idx, 'up2SD'].plot(color = 'r', ax = ax)
df.loc[df.index >= idx, 'down2SD'].plot(color = 'r', ax = ax)
df.loc[df.index >= idx, 'Data'].plot(color = 'b', ax = ax)
plt.show()

#resize the plot
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10,6]
plt.show()
```

[image]

Lines 2 (commented out) and 3 both work to plot all of the lines together as seen, however I wish to have the dates on the x-axis and also be able to be able to plot sections of the graph (defined by x-axis, i.e. date1 to date2).

Using line 3 I can plot with dates on the x-axis, however using ".iloc[300:]" like in line 2 does not appear to work as the 3 coloured lines disconnect from the main line as seen below:

```
ax = df.iloc[300:].plot('Date','Data',color = 'black', title = 'Past vs. Expected Future Path')
```

[image]

Using line 2, I can edit the x-axis' length, however it doesn't have dates on the x-axis.

Does anyone have any advice on how to both have dates and be able to edit the x-axis periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work as desired, you need to set the 'date' column as index of the dataframe. Otherwise, `df.plot` has no way to know what needs to be used as x-axis. With the date set as index, pandas accepts expressions such as `df.loc[df.index >= '20180101', 'data2']` to select a time range and a specific column.

Here is some example code to demonstrate the concept.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('20160101', '20191231', freq='D')
data1 = np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.2, len(dates))
data2 = np.random.normal(-0.7, 0.2, len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'data1':data1, 'data2':data2})

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df['data1'].iloc[300:].plot(color='crimson')
df.loc[df.index >= '20180101', 'data2'].plot(color='dodgerblue')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the explanation! Up voted and accepted.